# In Xcode, how would you go about having view controllers which are only accessible to the user if they perform a certain action in the app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The app I am making has multiple pages which the user swipes between. I need the user to be able to press a button and that create a new page in the app, and then also for the user to be able to delete that page of the app. Is there a way to generate/delete a view controller while the app is in use? Or do I need the view controllers already to exist and somehow lock/unlock them when the user adds/deletes them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create all the view controllers already and somehow lock/unlock them when the user adds/deletes them.

You can use [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller?changes=_4) for this purpose. Using UIPageViewController you will able add and delete view controllers.

Another way of implementing the same feature without the use view controllers as page is by using a [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) with its cells as page and paging enabled. Here in this case the size of the collection view cell be same as the size of the screen.

Comment: To go into more detail, I have a ViewController that acts as a template, and loads data based on the selection of the user. At the moment I have 3 of them, can you expand on what code would be needed to generate a entirely new view controller, that is set up in the same way as the template, without needing to have 3 separate view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

To have a snapchat like multiple view controller you could probably use a UIPageViewController with your custom views or a scroll view with paging enabled.SwipeView also seems like a nice implementation. see this stack overflow post for some other options and some implementation methods.